# Terraform - AWS Route53 Prevent Domain Deletion

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

I'm using terraform with AWS to manage an environment and want to be able to reference an existing route53 domain, add/modify records in the domain, etc.

If I run "terraform destroy" I want to delete all of the records added in the terraform code, but I do not want to delete the domain itself.

Is there a "proper" method for accomplishing this within the terraform config? Currently I have the domain information (zone ID, etc.) hardcoded into the .tf files, but if there is a way to reference this from the resource itself without allowing TF to destroy the domain that would seem ideal.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I discovered the answer to what I am looking for, which is to define the domain as "data" instead of as a resource in my TF code.

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "my_zone" {
  name = "myzone.net"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "myzone_net_mx_record" {
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.my_zone.zone_id}"
  name    = "*.myzone.net."
  type    = "MX"

  records = [
    "10 inbound-smtp.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
  ]

  ttl = "300"
}
```

This allows me to reference the zone ID without hardcoding the random string in there, but won't touch the base of the domain itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just looking for terraform resource life cycle option, prevent destroy. https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#prevent_destroy. Add this to your aws_route53_zone resource.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful in general, but in this case I don't want it to throw an error, I just want it to leave the domain in place and destroy everything else in a way that appears successful (an error will undoubtedly confuse someone down the road). I think I've figured out the solution though (see my answer to my question below).